# Having trouble figuring out how to place the API info for Rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Trying to figure out how to cache my Forecast.io request.

Currently I'm using both these gems:

```
gem 'forecast_io' 
gem 'figaro'
```

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to put the API key in the Rails low-level cache request. (first time I'm ever doing this, btw)

To clarify, when using `figaro` gem, I have both

`config/application.yml` file: (which has the following contents)

```
forecast_io_key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
```

and

`config/initializers/forecast_io.rb` file: (again the following contents)

```
require 'forecast_io'  

ForecastIO.configure do |config|    
  config.api_key = Figaro.env.forecast_io_key  
end
```

In my `forecast` model, this was my original working version:

```
class Forecast < ApplicationRecord

    def get_weather_data 
        ForecastIO.forecast(lat, lng) 
    end

end
```

Now trying to rewrite it to include the Rails cache but the rewritten version is not correct since it's no longer working and fetching the data:

```
class Forecast < ApplicationRecord

    def get_weather_data_paris
        Rails.cache.fetch(https://api.darksky.net/forecast/config.api_key/48.8566,2.3522, :expires => 1.hour) do
         ForecastIO.forecast(48.8566, 2.3522) 
        end
    end

end
```

How do I rewrite the `get_weather_data_paris` method so it includes the hidden API key, and caches it?

Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `:api_key` using `ForecastIO.api_key` like:

```
class Forecast < ApplicationRecord

  def get_weather_data_paris
    Rails.cache.fetch("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/#{ForecastIO.api_key}/48.8566,2.3522", :expires => 1.hour) do
     ForecastIO.forecast(48.8566, 2.3522) 
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: got this error: `undefined method 'configuration' for ForecastIO:Module Did you mean? configure`

Comment: also wondering if your answer takes in account of the fact that I'm using `figaro` gem? Hence I don't want to place the api key itself in the url ... which is why I'm having so much trouble making this work because I don't know how to fetch the api key in the `get_weather_data_paris` method above ... if you get what I mean?

Comment: oh, you did take in account of my `figario` gem stuff ... but the url still doesn't work ...

Comment: sorry, could you change ForecastIO.configuration.api_key to just ForecastIO.api_key

Comment: no need to apologize. =) your modification works. so, yay! the only question is that ... the `cache.fetch` doesn't seem to be working because I checked the Dark Sky's panel to see if the Paris hits #s stayed constant ... and it didn't ... does that mean that the `Rails.cache.fetch` method was wrong? I know .. long question .. should I make it another question post, or do you have any ideas?

Comment: it's this cache.fetch method that I'm trying to implement: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch

Comment: I think the fetch is working fine, if you're trying in Rails development mode you won't get cache, check this article http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/25/caching-in-development-environment-in-rails5.html

Comment: it's working! it's working! thanks to your article's link, I turned it on via `rails dev:cache` since I'm using Rails 5. Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It's great to help! take care :)

Comment: take care too! oy vey to the 15 character limit!